# How to validate select fields in html, laravel and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to make sure every field is required but this code only works on "input" tags but not on the select and textarea tags.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

**HERE IS MY BLADE**

```
<div class="tab">
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <select name="currency" class="choices form-control" id="devise{{ Auth::user()->cred->id }}"
                onchange="deviseSelect({{ Auth::user()->cred->id }})" required="true">
            <option value="" selected disabled>choose</option>
            <option value="USD">USD</option>
            <option value="FC">FC</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**HERE IS MY JAVASCRIPT FOR THE "SELECT" HTML TAG**

```
    <script>
        var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
        showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab
        function validateSelect()
        {
            // This function deals with validation of the form fields
            var x,z, i, valid = true;
            x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
            z = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("select");

            // A loop that checks every select field in the current tab:
            for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
                var option = z.options[i];
                // If a field is empty...
                if (option.value == "") {
                    // add an "invalid" class to the field:
                    z[i].className += " required";
                    // and set the current valid status to false:
                    valid = false;
                }
            }
            // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
            if (valid) {
                document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
            }
            return valid; // return the valid status
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: `required="true` doesn't look right to me. Use either just `required` or `required="required`. Preferably the former in HTML 5.

Comment: It's not a surprise to me at all that a function designed to check each select option doesn't work on an input or a textarea field since they don't have options. Your validation logic is just too specific. Maybe consider writing separate functions for that.

Comment: Thank you for using stack snippets. But the way you use them doesn't add any benefit over just using code blocks. Consider moving your HTML (blade) code to the snippet and combine them using a function call so that we can see, when (onChange, onClick of a button we currently don't see, etc.) the function is called.

Comment: Do you want any custom validation logic for your input and select fields or do you just want them to be validated alongside with your select fields using native form validation (e.g. `required` attribute)?

Comment: @shaedrich ,  i want a custom validation logic for select and textarea fields because i'm validating data step by step before the form get submitted.

Comment: Currently you only provided us with the validation logic for the select fields. You'd have to provide us with the logic you need for the textarea fields since how could we possibly know?

Comment: @shaedrich i edited my question. i just got rid of the textarea fields. if i get the right concept for the to validate the "select", i can easiy find a way to deal with the rests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I FOUND WHERE I'VE MISTAKEN**

I just changed something inside the for loop and everything started working perfectly.

```js
<script>
for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (z[i].value == "") {
        // add an "invalid" class to the field:
        z[i].className += " is-invalid";
        // and set the current valid status to false:
        valid = false;
    }
}
</script>
```